# Is it sensible to start a new enterprise large web application with linq2sql in 2012

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, orm

What is the current status of linq2sql and is it sensible to use it still?

I am about to start a very large project and have quite a lot of experience with it.

However I don't want to avoid EF if that is really the way to go. I do like the simplicity of linq2sql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion: no.

Why?

- EF in v4 is just as easy to get started with as Linq-to-SQL
- EF 4 also has options to do more complicated and advanced things - if you need to. No luck in Linq-to-SQL, really - it's simplicity is all there is - no advanced features
- EF 4 has various approaches to building your system - Linq-to-SQL only has "database-first"
- EF 4 allows you to **update your model** (if you're using the database-first approach) if your underlying database ever changes - is there any change it might?? No such luck with Linq-to-SQL - drop the table and drag it back on; tough luck if you modified table or column names, or added additional e.g. associations...
- Linq-to-SQL was really more of a proof of concept to show off the capabilities of LINQ, developed by the C# language team. It was never really meant to be a full-fledged ORM. EF on the other hand was developed by the ADO.NET database team, and was intended to be a real enterprise-grade ORM / conceptual data model. Linq-to-SQL will not see any further development to speak of - maybe a bugfix here or there. EF on the other hand is Microsoft's strategic platform - they'll heavily invest in it and continue development here (see e.g. the "EF Migrations" to automagically update your database schema from within code).

My personal take: if you start new and you're on .NET 4 (or can go with it): go with **EF v4**. You can't go wrong, you have all the niceties of Linq-to-SQL - and then quite a few more, if you need them some time in the future....

Comment: You forget the most important point: Linq2Sql is on life support - it will not be developped further. I would personally not go with EF either - crappy 2nd grade ORM compared to some open source systems, MS still needs 2 versions t obecome industrial quality.

Comment: See, I gave TomToms answer to a similar question ages ago - and it turns out I was totally wrong.  Theres nothing to suggest that Linq2Sql is on life support or that development has stopped on it, it has gained new features with .Net 4.0 and is being developed in .Net 4.5.  Both projects will run side by side for the forseeable future, as they solve differnet issues.

Comment: @TomTom, actually he mentioned that in his last bullet point. And as for the third point, Linq to SQL also supports model-first development.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I may give it a shot. Any suggested tutorials?

Comment: @ChrisBarry: there's the [MSDN intro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx), [Julie Lerman's eight tutorials](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/eight-entity-framework-tutorials-on-datadeveloper-net/), some [videos on the ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/05/20/how-do-i-new-entity-framework-videos.aspx), [ScottGu's Code-First Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) and certainly a lot more, if you just Google or Bing for "EF Tutorial"

Comment: I'll be going for EF then, and code first does look rather appealing after having been working with Google App Engine recently.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd try to make it such that the database layer is an implementation detail, behind a view-model, repository layer, and other such devices. Then the only question is:

> does it work?

To which the answer will probably be "yes", but by abstrating that you can change it without much risk / re-work. Perhaps to the "fuller" ORMs (NH, EF, LLBLGen etc) - or perhaps the lighter micro-ORMs (dapper, simple.data, massive etc).

If L2S lets you get started quicky, there's no reason it can't be used. It might not be my first choice now, but it is a good tool, and I find it more intuitive than EF in many areas.

The key, though, is not painting yourself into a technological corner where change is too expensive.

Comment: Thanks Marc, Yes it will be abstracted behind repositories and services, so that is fine. I may give EF a go, and see how different/heavy it really is.

Answer (score 1):

Linq-2-SQL is dead... no matter you hear around
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx